# How to use Yoast SEO Premium properly

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, yoast

The Yoast plugin creates its own redirect map when the URLs of published posts are changed. We need a function that will run after changes are made to the redirect map.

But for some reasons, I can't make it work even I have a lot args

---

```
// This throws an error with: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function handle_yoast_term_redirect_slug_change(), 

 function handle_yoast_term_redirect_slug_change($create_redirect, $term_id, $term, $term_before) {
     $old_slug = $term_before->slug;
     $new_slug = $term->slug;
 
     if ($old_slug !== $new_slug) {
         $redirect_url = get_term_link($term_id, $term->taxonomy);
         wp_redirect($redirect_url);
         exit();
     }
 
     return $create_redirect;
 }
 
 add_filter('Yoast\WP\SEO\term_redirect_slug_change', 'handle_yoast_term_redirect_slug_change', 10, 4);
```

This is working pretty fine but when it comes to termRedirectSlug it won't

```
function handle_yoast_post_redirect_slug_change( $create_redirect, $post_id, $post, $post_before ) {
     $old_slug = $post_before->post_name;
     $new_slug = $post->post_name;
     var_dump($old_slug, $new_slug);
     if ( $old_slug !== $new_slug ) {
         $redirect_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
         var_dump($redirect_url);
         wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
         exit();
     }
 
     return $create_redirect;
 }

 add_filter( 'Yoast\WP\SEO\post_redirect_slug_change', 'handle_yoast_post_redirect_slug_change', 999, 4 );
```

Comment: I'm not finding much for documentation, but what I can find is showing that it just accepts a [single parameter](https://developer.yoast.com/customization/yoast-seo-premium/disabling-automatic-redirects-notifications/). Do you have other documentation that you can reference?